# PHP md5 insertion in localhost

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to insert an md5 value for password field. When I check the query, for example:

```
c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
```

but it is getting inserted as

```
c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f7584
```

(Note that `9b` is missing to the original value)

My query code is:

```
INSERT INTO employee_list (employee_id,password)
VALUES('user12','c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b')
```

Comment: What is the type of `password` in your table

Comment: Go to your database. Edit your password field and increase length of your field.

Comment: password varchar(30), but just now i got the answer from damien-pirsy,.. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your `password` field is defined as `VARCHAR(30)` (IIRC, it's the default value when you create a table in phpmyadmin), and md5 is always 32 chars long.

Make the DB fieled as `VARCHAR(32)` (or greater, those extra bytes won't penalize your application) and it won't get cut.

If you allow me, I suggest you drop the md5 hashing, which isn't considered safe enough (collisions, rainbow tables, etc) and go for a better and slower algorythm. PHP 5.5 has the [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function now which uses bcrypt, but if you are on a lower version you can use [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function with CRYPT_BLOWFISH flag. Beware that in this case the field needs to be longer than 32 characters.

Comment: @Hanna If this answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking the checkmark - this (and upvoting) is the best way to say thanks.